# Is there a way possible to send an ADB command to a firestick which would rotate the screen 180°?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, display, amazon-fire-tv

The purpose for this is that I have a projector upside down mounted on the ceiling (thats where the mounting screws are unfortunately) and I don't have the original remote to tell the screen to flip orientation as i normally would do. I've tried countless "Universal" remotes and nothing works on the projector so I was hoping there would be a way to totally flip the view of the firestick 180° so that I could see the image right side up, since I only use the projector with a firestick this would solve my problem.

Thanks in advance, I've connected to the device in ADB and tried some commands which appear to work in the command prompt but don't affect the screen at all while looking at it.

Comment: bump i really need help with this

Answer (score 0):

adb -s (IP) shell settings put system user_rotation 2

https://medium.com/@navalkishoreb/rotate-android-device-screen-using-adb-commands-not-emulator-94ab1a749b87